# This day in history VI

Tags: riddle, history

It was defectedWBC who got the last one. Well done! On this day (8th May) an event happened. Can you tell me the event, explain the clues and tell me what year it happened.

A sickly-sweet syrup-like substance
At first was sold at about fivepence
T'was a remedy, an all-round cure
Now across the globe is 'click, fizz, pour'

By the name of an actor
And the place of an activist
Became a worldwide phenomenon
For which you can *open happiness*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Introduction of Coca Cola, 1886

A sickly-sweet syrup-like substance

> Cocal cola typically contains 12-US-fluid-ounce (350 ml) can contains 38 grams (1.3 oz) of sugar (usually in the form of high fructose corn syrup)

At first was sold at about fivepence

> The introductory price was near 5 pence

T'was a remedy, an all-round cure

Now across the globe is 'click, fizz, pour'

> Drugstore soda fountains were popular in the United States at the time due to the belief that carbonated water was good for the health, and Pemberton's new drink was marketed and sold as a patent medicine, John Pemberton claiming it a cure for many diseases, including morphine addiction, indigestion, nerve disorders, headaches, and impotence.
>
>
>  People open a bottle 'click', it fizzes 'fizz' and then pours it in a glass to drink 'pour'.

By the name of an actor

> Imogene Coca, although OP wants the British actor Steve Pemberton as the inventor of Coca-Cola was named Pemberton.

And the place of an activist

> Mayilamma was an Indian social activist whose claim to fame was the campaign against Coca-Cola Company in Plachimada in Palakkad, Kerala.
>
>
> Here the OP wanted Atlanta (where it was first created and sold) was home to Martin Luther King Jr.

*Weird that there are more than 1 solution to the above 2 lines.*

Became a worldwide phenomenon

For which you can open happiness

> Everyone across the world enjoys a glass of 'open happiness' now. Open happiness being one of the marketing slogans of Coca-Cola.

Comment: Spot on except for the actor and activist. +1

Comment: Weird that it fits...

Comment: Yea. I was thinking of rot13(Gur Oevgvfu npgbe Fgrir Crzoregba nf gur vairagbe bs Pbpn-Pbyn jnf anzrq Crzoregba naq Ngynagn (jurer vg jnf svefg perngrq naq fbyq) jnf ubzr gb Znegva Yhgure Xvat We.)

Comment: Let me add that to the answer. That is a different line of thought, but matches. This is interesting that there can be 2 answers!

Comment: Yes. It's said that a riddle with multiple answers is flawed and I'm not great at riddle creation but I think it can be very interesting what people come up with. You can tell a lot about someone from that.

Answer (score 3):

Today in

> 1886, the [first Coca Cola was sold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-Cola#19th_century_historical_origins)

A sickly-sweet syrup-like substance

> Coca Cola is a soda

T'was a remedy, an all-round cure

> Coca Cola was originally sold as a medicine

*open happiness*

> Was one of the slogans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Happiness

Comment: do you mind telling me who was first to answer? You were both so close either way +1

Comment: I was the first (you can hover over the timestamp and see mine was posted 8:38:03 and Yuzuriha 8:38:12) but their answer is more complete (right now).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help!